# GitHub Actions: Unable to find the input file with GitHub Actions

Tags: python-3.x, github, github-actions

I'm trying to run "make lint" command. For that, I have written below GitHub Action:

```
name: main

on: push

jobs:

  super-lint:

    name: Lint code base
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: TESTING SERGEY      
        run: make lint 

      - name: Run Super-Linter
        uses: github/super-linter@v3
        env:
          DEFAULT_BRANCH: master
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

I'm using Windows 10, but it's giving me an error:

```
 Run make lint
 make lint
 shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
 poetry run flake8 brain_games
 process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, poetry run flake8 brain_games, ...) failed.
 make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.

 mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:5: lint] Error 2
 Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I did try to change Powershell default folder, did not work. I also trying to add path "C:\Python_Work_for_Hexlet\python-project-lvl1/" right after "run: make lint ", also did not work.

Please help!

Comment: Looks like poetry is either not installed or not in the path. Try using an action like https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-poetry

Comment: I did try . Same error

Comment: What do you mean by VCS? You're using `windows-latest`.

Comment: i mean Visual Studio Code.

Comment: The code in GitHub Actions isn't run on your computer (Windows 10 + VSC + poetry). It is run on a GitHub hosted runner running `windows-latest` (resloves to `windows-2019` at the time of this post) and the software specified at  https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md. This doesn't contain poetry.

Comment: i did add lines to install poetry but it shows the same error.

Comment: What's the output if you add the step `- run: poetry --version` directly after the `setup-poetry` step?